# Special character insertion in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

***Xyz's Goods Hospital @ St. Petersburg Division*** is stored in a string variable named _value. Now what will be the C# sting query to insert this value in a MS SQL table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO your_table (field1) SELECT @val",
    dbconn)) 
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val", your_string);
    try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
    catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
}
```

**EDITED after OP comment:**
If you have to insert in multiple columns you can use this different query:

```
"INSERT INTO your_table (field1, field2, field3) SELECT @val1, @val2, @val3"
```

and in code add and assign value to every query parameter .

Comment: you have to replace ' with ''

Comment: +1. Much better than trying to get escaping right by hand (which they probably planned).

Comment: If I want to insert in multiple column at a time then what should I write in query instead of 'SELECT @val'

Comment: My problem already solved but why my following code didn't work?

string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COLUMN_NAME) VALUES ( @value )";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@value", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters["@value"].Value = myValue
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score -1):

Assign the value to the going into the database as 
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(named _value);

and then while retrieving it use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value) . Even if you enter it directly it should insert it ..
Could please be more specific what exactly do you want to achieve from this

Comment: Why should OP use `HtmlEncode` with a string to be inserted in a database? Think if later he has to query that value...

Comment: There are much better solutions to this problem than using HTML entities.